# Drag and Drop text in Android Studio editor causes an Exception

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I can no longer do a drag and drop on any text in Android Studio 2.3, when I do it, the selected text just disappear, and I get an Exception in the Event Log

Here is a video showing the problem http://recordit.co/lsZuvQluol

And here is the complete stacktrace :

```
Assertion failed
java.lang.Throwable
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.assertTrue(Logger.java:158)
at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.assertTrue(Logger.java:167)
at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.lambda$null$11(EditorImpl.java:6497)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:898)
at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.lambda$handleDrop$12(EditorImpl.java:6478)
at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:129)
at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl.handleDrop(EditorImpl.java:6478)
at com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorImpl$MyTransferHandler.importData(EditorImpl.java:6522)
at javax.swing.TransferHandler.importData(TransferHandler.java:827)
at javax.swing.TransferHandler$DropHandler.drop(TransferHandler.java:1544)
at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.drop(DropTarget.java:455)
at javax.swing.TransferHandler$SwingDropTarget.drop(TransferHandler.java:1282)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:538)
at sun.lwawt.macosx.CDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(CDropTargetContextPeer.java:143)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchDropEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:852)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:776)
at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetEvent.dispatch(SunDropTargetEvent.java:48)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processDropTargetEvent(Container.java:4599)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4461)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:795)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:627)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:387)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Your problem is with the IDE itself, so submit a bug report.

Comment: @cricket_007 the issue seems to be caused by a third-party plug-in, bug report for IDE is [already submitted](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168934).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disabling](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-and-disabling-plugins.html) [Markdown Navigator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7896-markdown-navigator) plug-in should help.

Bug report:

- [2.3.4 Breaks drag and drop of text](https://github.com/vsch/idea-multimarkdown/issues/406)

Another fix is to [update to the EAP plug-in version](https://github.com/vsch/idea-multimarkdown/issues/406#issuecomment-283732157).

Answer (score -1):

Try `Clean & Rebuild` project. Restarting Android Studio may help.

Comment: Nothing to do with the project, it does this with all projects, I've also tried to delete the preferences folder, but still have the same issue